# Embedded Web Server

Tags: java, php, web-applications, webserver

We currently have a web application which should be accessible from multiple sub-domains and from multiple actual domains. E.g. clients sign up and if they want to they can use their own domains. As far as I know this would be achieved by them pointing that domains A record at us and then our web server, which would have to be embedded so we can update at run-time, adding a virtual host dynamically.

Our web application is written in PHP (although playing around with HipHop to convert to C++) with static HTML and CSS. This web application communicates with a back-end Java API that uses the Restlet framework.

Does anyone know of a web server that could be embedded that will work with PHP (and would work with HipHop if we used that)? I have had a look at AppWeb but I wondered if there were any others.

I wonder if maybe I would be better moving my web app to something like Java and using Jetty?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to "embed" the web server - I'm not sure the term "embed" is applicable here either.  If you're hosting the app, just set up Apache to handle multiple domains.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. Anyway, I don't think that your requirement (being able to add a virtual host dynamically) justifies using a embedded HTTP server. You can already do that with Apache without restarting it (i.e.: `apachectl reload`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you need is to lookup the

```
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

which would be different as clients uses different domains.

Regarding minimalistic webserver, I've found mongoose to flexible and easy to setup.

(uses php-cgi).

http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/

regards,
//t

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by accepting wildcard subdomains in apache, and dispatching based on the server name in PHP.

An example apache configuration can be found [here](http://steinsoft.net/index.php?site=programming/articles/apachewildcarddomain).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get correctly where you want to embed it. But if PHP is a requirement, there is the option of using http://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Server. It's rather minimalistic, but should thus be easily adaptable and have less issues with a HipHop transformation.

The second alternative would be Nanoweb. While that's designed as a real webserver and feature-wise comparable to Apache, it's not suitable for embedding. But there are probably others, if you want to go that particular route.